# Get User ID in Microsoft teams without bot

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

When following the current documentation microsoft provides, it will most likely spit you out at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet#get-the-user-aad-id-user-id-team-id-or-channel-id). Which is a guide on building bots, and has no direct instructions for actually retrieving a user's ID for sending, that does not require the user interacting first.

I'm building an incoming webhook to a channel, not a bot. So how can I get the ID's of the users I would like to mention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the correct privileges (I personally do not), there is a "unified" API that Microsoft provides that can [supply the information here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

Otherwise, if you open the web version of teams, you can find the user ID in the URL of the conversation you have with said people.

teams.microsoft.com/_#/conversations/19:{you}_{the person your talking to's ID}@unq.gbl.spaces?ctx=chat